# JSVC can't be build

Tags: java, makefile, centos, jsvc

I can't build [JSVC](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) locally on Centos 7 from tarball

```
http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/source/commons-daemon-1.0.15-src.tar.gz
tar -zxf commons-daemon-1.0.15-src.tar.gz
```

I have JRE installed at the location `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64`:

I do according to the instruction:

```
cd /opt/install
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/source/commons-daemon-1.0.15-src.tar.gz
tar -zxf commons-daemon-1.0.15-src.tar.gz
cd ./commons-daemon-1.0.15-src/src/native/unix
./configure && make
```

Despite I have `$JAVA_HOME` pointed exactly to `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64` the `./configure` script still requires something to substitute missing `$JAVA_HOME` like `sudo ./configure --with-java=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64`

But it can't define the needed folder correctly even withthis parameter. The only option that allows me to build is

```
sudo ./configure --with-java=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include --with-os-type=linux
```

So it requires `/include` part to be here to build the full correct path.

Bu the later causes problems on the next step, when I do `make`. It puts that surplus `/include` to the path that is a parameter of gcc and I'm getting the errors like that:

```
sudo make -I /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64(cd native; make  all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/install/commons-daemon-1.0.15-src/src/native/unix/native'
gcc -g -O2 -DOS_LINUX -DDSO_DLFCN -DCPU=\"amd64\" -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/include/linux -c java.c -o java.o
java.c:24:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
```

So, how I can work it around? The first part doesn't work without /include, the second part doesn't work because of it.

Comment: Maybe try to add "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/bin" into your PATH variable.

Comment: What is the thought of using JSVC?

Comment: I order to compile JNI-related things one needs JDK, not just JRE. Make sure that you have `jni.h` by issuing `find <path-to-jdk> -name jni.h'`

Comment: @hooknc to follow an installation instruction

Comment: @user3159253 I'm using JDK, that's clearly seen in the logs output, but that's a usefull advice, first I tried with JRE, but not to the time of this question, but before

Comment: @IgorKanshyn it doesn't help, since it looks for JAVA_HOME but ignores it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a dirty hack like changing manually one file being produced on the `./configure` stage and before the `make` stage.

In the root folder together with `Makefile` we have `Makedefs` file

Here replace

```
INCLUDES =  -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/linux
```

with

```
INCLUDES =  -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351-amd64/include/include/linux
```

and compilation would succeed.

I have no idea what hould be done by design according to the JSVC instruction.